# How to replace all files NAME in A folder with character "_" if the character ASCII encoding is greater than 128 use powershell

Tags: powershell, ascii, special-characters

The example file name is
PO 2171 Cresco REVISED.pdf
.....
Many of these files, the file name is not standard, the space position is not fixed.
The middle space is characters ASCII code greater than 128, and I want to replace characters ASCII code greater than 128 with "_" one-time.

I haven't learned Powershell yet.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you are going to need regex.

Below I'm using the ASCII range 32 - 129 (in hex `\x20-\x81`) to also replace any control characters:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File) | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '[^\x20-\x81]' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[^\x20-\x81]+', '_' }
```

Regex Details:

```
[^\x20-\x81]     Match a single character NOT in the range between ASCII character 0x20 (32 decimal) and ASCII character 0x81 (129 decimal)
   +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Make sure the space ASCII code is 160

Comment: @OLDwong To clarify: Ascii 160  is used in HTML and is not a normal space, but the code for a non-breaking space a.k.a. `&nbsp;`. The space character has Ascii value 32 (in hex: 20)

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72329168/45375) is effective, but there's a simpler, more direct solution, using the .NET [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) [Unicode code block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) **`\p{IsBasicLatin}`**, which directly **matches any ASCII-range [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character** (all .NET strings are Unicode strings, internally composed of [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code units).

Its **negation, `\P{IsBasicLatin}`** (note the uppercase `P`), matches any character *outside* the ASCII range, so that you can use the following to replace all non-ASCII-range characters with `_`, with the help of the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```sh
(Get-ChildItem -File) |  # Get all files in the current dir.
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\P{IsBasicLatin', '_' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- Enclosing the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call in `(...)` ensures that all matching files are collected *first*, before renaming is performed. This prevents problems that could arise from already-renamed files re-entering the enumeration of files.
- Since only *files* (`-File`) are to be renamed, you needn't worry about file names that do *not* contain non-ASCII-range characters: [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) quietly ignores attempts to rename files to the name they already have.

  - Unfortunately, this is *not* true for *directories*, where such an attempt causes an error; this unfortunate discrepancy, present as of PowerShell 7.2.4, is the subject of [GitHub issue #14903](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14903).
- Strictly speaking, .NET characters (`[char]` ([`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char)) instances) are 16-bit [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) code units (UTF-16), which can individually only represent a complete Unicode character in the so-called [BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), i.e. in the code-point range `0x0`-`0xFFFF`. Unicode characters beyond that range, notably emoji such as , require representation by *two* .NET `[char]` instances, so-called surrogate pairs.  Therefore, the above solution replaces such characters with *two* `_` characters, as the following example demonstrates:

  ```sh
    PS> 'A !' -replace '\P{IsBasicLatin}', '_'

    A __!        # !! *two* '_' chars.
  ```